Does 1 John 1:7 mean fellowship with God, or Man?
1 John 1:6-7 (NASB)

6 If we say that we have fellowship with Him and yet walk in the
darkness, we lie and do not practice the truth; 7 but if we walk in
the Light as He Himself is in the Light, we have fellowship with
one another, and the blood of Jesus His Son cleanses us from all sin.

When John says we have fellowship with one another, does he mean fellowship with God? This makes sense when contrasted against verse 6, but the use of "one another" seems to point to fellowship with other followers of Jesus Christ.

The answer is given in the previous verses. This epistle of John starts with him talking about he who was from the beginning, who had been seen with literal eyes, beheld by the apostles and many other believers, and their hands had actually handled, or touched this One, who is the Word of the Life. This Word was with the Father and was manifested to them - Jesus Christ. Then, from verse 3 comes the 'fellowship' bit.
John begins by taking about himself and those reading his epistle having fellowship with each other. Humans having fellowship with other humans. But, he instantly adds that their fellowship is with the Father, and with his Son, Jesus Christ.
Verse 5 then speaks of God being light, and that there is no darkness in God.
Verse 6 shows that those who claim to have fellowship with him (God), but who walk in the darkness (i.e. they are not walking in the light of God) are lying.
Verse 7 shows that those who walk in the light of God, in fellowship with God, also have fellowship with other humans who do likewise. That is because all those believers who are walking in the light of God are cleansed from every sin by the blood of Christ, the Son.
The answer is that without professed Christians walking in the light of God, their professed fellowship with other humans will be a lie. Their fellowship will be no more than that of people coming together every week at their bowling, or badminton, or exercise club. To elevate fellowship between believers to the level John was speaking of requires those believers to be walking (daily, I might add) in the light of God. Therefore, the verse in question speaks of both fellowship with God and fellowship with human believers. It is not an "either" "or" thing. Both are completely bound up together.

1 John 1:6-7 (NASB)

6 If we say that we have fellowship with Him and yet walk in the darkness, we lie and do not practice the truth; 7 but if we walk in the Light as He Himself is in the Light, we have fellowship with one another, and the blood of Jesus His Son cleanses us from all sin.

Verse 6 establishs the truth of this argument - if we have fellowship with God, we walk in the Light.
Following this line of reasoning, verse 7 can be interpreted as such;

When we have fellowship with God, we have fellowship with one another......

Therefore, the term 'one another' exclusively refer to brethen, as the preceding statement establishes God as the source of this fellowship connection.

Short Answer: "one another" is referring to fellow believers. However, the whole thing also points to fellowship with God.
I would say that there are two applications for when believers walk in the light:

Believers will have community and friendship with one another.
Believers will experience forgiveness.

Fellowship with God: If we look at it with the context of the verse 6, we see that it contrasts walking in the light (and having fellowship with God) with walking in darkness (and lying about having fellowship with Him).
Fellowship with other believers: Verse 7 refers to the fellowship believers have with each other when they walk in the light. This is supported by the use of the term “one another,” which often refers to interactions among members of the Christian community.
MacLaren's Expositions notes:

Now there are three things: walking in the light, which is the only
Christian walk; the companions of those who walk in the light; and the
progressive cleansing which is given.


Examples of “one another,” referring to interactions among members of the Christian community:
Unity. One third of the one-another commands deal with the unity of the church.

Be at peace with one another (Mk 9:50)
Don’t grumble among one another (Jn 6:43)
Be of the same mind with one another (Ro 12:16, 15:5)
Accept one another (Ro 15:7)
Wait for one another before beginning the Eucharist (1 Co 11:33)
Don’t bite, devour, and consume one another—seriously, guys, don’t
eat each other (Ga 5:15)
Don’t boastfully challenge or envy one another (Ga 5:26).
Gently, patiently tolerate one another (Ep 4:2)
Be kind, tender-hearted, and forgiving to one another (Ep 4:32)
Bear with and forgive one another (Co 3:13)
Seek good for one another, and don’t repay evil for evil (1 Th 5:15)
Don’t complain against one another (Jas 4:11, 5:9)
Confess sins to one another (Jas 5:16)

Love. One third of them instruct Christians to love one another.

Love one another (Jn 13:34, 15:12, 17; Ro 13:8; 1 Th 3:12, 4:9; 1 Pe
1:22; 1 Jn 3:11, 4:7, 11; 2 Jn 5)
Through love, serve one another (Ga 5:13)
Tolerate one another in love (Ep 4:2)
Greet one another with a kiss of love (1 Pe 5:14)
Be devoted to one another in love (Ro 12:10)

Humility. About 15% stress an attitude of humility and deference among believers.

Give preference to one another in honor (Ro 12:10)
Regard one another as more important than yourselves (Php 2:3)
Serve one another (Ga 5:13)
Wash one another’s feet (Jn 13:14)
Don’t be haughty: be of the same mind (Ro 12:16)
Be subject to one another (Ep 5:21)
Clothe yourselves in humility toward one another (1 Pe 5:5)

Here’s the rest:

Do not judge one another, and don’t put a stumbling block in a
brother’s way (Ro 14:13)
Greet one another with a kiss (Ro 16:16; 1 Co 16:20; 2 Co 13:12)
Husbands and wives: don’t deprive one another of physical intimacy (1
Co 7:5)
Bear one another’s burdens (Ga 6:2)
Speak truth to one another (Ep 4:25)
Don’t lie to one another (Co 3:9)
Comfort one another concerning the resurrection (1 Th 4:18)
Encourage and build up one another (1 Th 5:11)
Stimulate one another to love and good deeds (He 10:24)
Pray for one another (Jas 5:16)
Be hospitable to one another (1 Pe 4:9)




Reference




https://overviewbible.com/one-another-infographic/



